# How to write Partitions to Postgres using foreachPartition (pySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and trying to wite df partitions to Postgres
here is my code:

```
//csv_new is a DF with nearly 40 million rows and 6 columns

csv_new.foreachPartition(callback) // there are 19204 partitions
def callback(iterator):
   print(iterator)

// the print gives me itertools.chain object
```

but when writing to DB with following code:

```
iterator.write.option("numPartitions", count).option("batchsize", 
 1000000).jdbc(url=url, table="table_name", mode=mode, 
  properties=properties)
```

gives an error:

> *AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'write'  mode is append and properties are set

Any leads on how to write the df partition to DB

Comment: May be I am wrong but would the DF.write not already be performed in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that.

The documentation states it along these lines and it occurs in parallel:

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
  .option("dbtable", "T1")
  .option("url", url1)
  .option("user", "User")
  .option("password", "Passwd")
  .option("numPartitions", "5") // to define parallelism
  .save()
```

There are some performances aspects to consider, but that can be googled.

Comment: UI have tried doing this but it fails with memory error in my case . i have increased the GC as well as heap memory but it does not help

Comment: But that is the way to do it. That is a different question you are asking then. See http://www.gatorsmile.io/numpartitionsinjdbc/

Comment: @user10121535 If your code fails with GC errors you can be pretty sure that the problem isn't here.

Comment: @thebluephantom, how efficient do you think this works for millions(50) of records ?

Comment: 50M is nothing in terms of Big Data, unless u expect in 1 second. But this is an RDBMS so you an increase parallelism as shown above and I would think may be non-logging modes exist in postgres as well. E.g. https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-performance-with-unlogged-tables-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 2):

Many Thanks to @thebluephantom ,just a little add on in case the the table already exists save mode also needs to be defined.
Following was my implementation which worked :-

```
mode = "Append"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://DatabaseIp:port/DB Name"
properties = {"user": "username", "password": "password"}

df.write
  .option("numPartitions",partitions here)
  .option("batchsize",your batch size default is 1000)
  .jdbc(url=url, table="tablename", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```